# Phonegap Android SmsSendingPlugin not returning sms not sent

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, sms

I'm using https://github.com/Pyo25/phonegap-sms-sending-plugin to send SMS and it sends fine, however, even if there is no network coverage/ flight mode the plugin still returns me status.OK though the SMS is not sent.

Is there anyway to assure or check the message status?

I have tried registering a broadcast receiver in my sendSMS java but it doesn't register

```
 registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
  switch (getResultCode())
  {
    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      break;
    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      break;
    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      break;
    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      break;
    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      break;
  }
}
```

}, new IntentFilter(smsSent));

Comment: Can you please post the javascript code you are using?

Comment: The plugin itself has its javascript to call cordova, can be found here https://github.com/Pyo25/phonegap-sms-sending-plugin/blob/master/assets/www/SmsSendingPlugin.js..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works GREAT! it has a sent and delivery intent

http://androidopera.blogspot.com/2013/03/smsplugin-phonegap-android.html#comment-form

Comment: what should we give when we call the sms function..i had just given `sendSMS.send(‘Mobile Number’, ‘Text’, ‘Call back function on complete’);`  and i got this error `05-31 15:03:05.879: E/Web Console(15239): Uncaught ReferenceError: sendSMS is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:14`.. **please guide me through this**